How to keep or transfer edge attributes after using Mesh To Curve Node?
I have a problem with a node setup that converts the imported mesh to N-gons mesh (I use this to clean up the imported mesh for the next instancing module nodes).
And the integer attributes assigned to the edges are removed after using the Mesh To Curve Node.
As you can see in the screenshot below, 3 attributes: blank, door, and balcony were assigned to some edges.

This happens after using the node setup. The attributes were removed.

I tried to capture these attributes the way I did with the Position attribute but it did not work, maybe I missed something.

How can we keep these assigned attributes while keeping my node setup?
See my nodes in the following file.


I think edge attributes are lost by Mesh to Curve node. Could you try and capture in Point domain before this node ? An other way could be to Sample Nearest edges after the Fill Curve nodes with target the Group Input Geometry.

This is not too simple, but a few hints: the attributes are kept in the point domain (but that means they will be interpolated and will probably be messy). You can use the final edge positions to "sample nearest" edge of the original geometry. The drawback here is that the final geometry doesn't seem to follow the original and some weird results appear. You could also try to resample the curves in small segments to use the point domain in a better way (just use float instead of boolean, then you will have interpolations that make sense or are wrong only at corners.

I do not understand why the "Fill Curve Keep Position" frame, but is there any reason not to simply proceed like this: https://i.sstatic.net/eArFu1ov.png ?

The frame [Fill Curve Keep Position] is used to fill any closed curve, preventing the flattening of curves on the plan, unlike the way the node [Fill Curve] operates.
Your node works fine. Thank you, @SteftAncien.

Anything against just deleting the inner edges without all those weird set positions?
Anyway, the solution is "store the attribute" again sampling from edge position to nearest edge.


It works! Thank you, @Daniel Moller.
